# C++ program is crashing for some unknown reason

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ recently, and thought I would test my mettle with Project Euler problems. I solved the first two, but I am stuck on the third. It is compiling correctly without any errors, but it is crashing as soon as it is executed. I tried removing the nested for loops to isolate the problem, and it still crashed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  float quot;
  int num = 0;
  int array[100];
  float next;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
      {
          if((i % j) == 0)
          {
            quot=j/i;
            num=num+1;
          }

          if (num=2)
          {
            array[i]=i;
          }
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if((13195 % i) == 0)
    {
      std::cout << i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what the point of any of this code is... But you are assigning to num in your `if (num=2)`

Comment: Looks like you're dividing by 0 somewhere.

Comment: Time to break out the debugger.

Comment: Well, this is Project Euler problem 3. I am sure there's a simpler way to do this, but I thought I would give it a try. Basically, I am trying to find prime factors of 13195. So first I find all prime factors (upto 100), and then find all factors divisible by 13195.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `if((i%j)==0)` if `i` and `j` are zero, your next line is dividing i and j. This is division by zero.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Isn't the % operator meant to find the remainder? So theoretically, if i=1 and j=1, then their remainder would be 0. But the division is perfectly logical, is it not?

Comment: That division is logical, but if i and j are zero, which they are the first time through the loop, you're dividing by zero.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I knew it was going to be something easy ;)

Comment: From MSDN: "The modulus, or remainder, operator divides number1 by number2 and returns only the remainder."